# Как в Pandas применить функцию и записать её результат сразу в два столбца?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, статистика

Использую для вычисления значения собственную функцию, но она возвращает сразу два значения. В инструкции pandas не нашел способа получить оба значения из функции и записать их в два разных столбца Dataframe.

Думаю не логично вызывать функцию дважды для формирования каждого столбца. Но способа это сделать не нашел. ПРошу помочь, кто знает как это сделать.
[Вот](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j0sIiRFY-kx7Uh9LLBORzuupilp5b2QZ) ссылка на свой блокнот с моим кодом

И вот мой код, если так будет удобнее:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# загружаю файл с данными. 
# Первый столбец обозначает принадлежность к одному их трех классов обозначенных цифрами 1, 0, -1
fn = 'http://kramer.su/media/cms_page_media/downloads/dataset_corr200.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=None, header=None, delimiter=';')

# Уменьшаю размер датафрейма для наглядности. Вообще полный файл состоит из нескольких тысяч строк
df = df.iloc[60:71, :]

# получаю таблицу корреляций по строкам, исключая первый столбец
dfcorr = df.iloc[:, 395:].T.corr() 

# обнуляю диагональ
dfcorr.values[tuple([np.arange(len(dfcorr))]*2)] = 0
# dfcorr['top_3_corr'] = dfcorr.apply(lambda c: c.nlargest(3).index.tolist())

# # добавляю в таблицу корреляций столбец-маркер, указывающий принадлежность вектора к одному из трех классов 
dfcorr["CLASS"] = df[0]

def max_corr_noise(cor):
  selection_replica = list()
  noise_list = list()
  priznaki = list(dfcorr['CLASS'])
  cat = cor['CLASS']
  
  for idx, crl in enumerate(cor[:-1]):
    if priznaki[idx] != cat:
      noise_list.append(cor[idx]) # список шумов
    else:
      selection_replica.append(cor[idx]) # трастовый список
  
  max_noise = max(noise_list)
  replica = min(selection_replica) # нужно добавить во второй столбец "min_replica". Как это сделать?
  
  return max_noise
  
dfcorr['max_noise'] = dfcorr.apply(max_corr_noise, axis=1)
dfcorr['min_replica'] = "как сюда добавить значение переменной 'replica'?"
```

Речь идет о применении функции "**max_corr_noise**".
Нужно чтобы она записала свой результат:

```
в поле max_noise записать переменную max_noise
в поле min_replica записать значение переменной replica
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы добавить сразу два (несколько) столбцов в Pandas DataFrame функция должна возвращать DataFrame размерности: (`число строк исходного DF`, `число добавляемых столбцов`).

Пример:

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
   a  b  c
0  7  4  9
1  9  1  9
2  3  3  9

In [54]: df[['new1','new2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,2)))

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
   a  b  c  new1  new2
0  7  4  9     5     8
1  9  1  9     3     9
2  3  3  9     0     9
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [76]: def f(row):
    ...:     return pd.Series([np.min(row), np.max(row)])
    ...:

In [77]: dfcorr[['min','max']] = dfcorr.apply(f, axis=1)

In [78]: dfcorr
Out[78]:
          60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70  CLASS       min       max
60  0.000000  0.275735  0.307580  0.776632  0.506524 -0.061436  0.500843  0.191837  0.536049 -0.011832  0.024688      0 -0.061436  0.776632
61  0.275735  0.000000  0.267424  0.286705  0.055328  0.392358  0.104233  0.440715  0.153645  0.304410  0.381320      0  0.000000  0.440715
62  0.307580  0.267424  0.000000  0.307773  0.100814  0.163128  0.660256  0.358847  0.134464  0.073466  0.106633      1  0.000000  1.000000
63  0.776632  0.286705  0.307773  0.000000  0.679462 -0.017250  0.248416  0.216678  0.686844  0.196126  0.152874      0 -0.017250  0.776632
64  0.506524  0.055328  0.100814  0.679462  0.000000 -0.010464  0.075906  0.021292  0.844402  0.122480  0.005507      1 -0.010464  1.000000
65 -0.061436  0.392358  0.163128 -0.017250 -0.010464  0.000000 -0.150592  0.759488  0.114335  0.357669  0.174943     -1 -1.000000  0.759488
66  0.500843  0.104233  0.660256  0.248416  0.075906 -0.150592  0.000000  0.032443  0.178791 -0.093669  0.168891     -1 -1.000000  0.660256
67  0.191837  0.440715  0.358847  0.216678  0.021292  0.759488  0.032443  0.000000  0.180341  0.218450  0.074552      1  0.000000  1.000000
68  0.536049  0.153645  0.134464  0.686844  0.844402  0.114335  0.178791  0.180341  0.000000  0.067946  0.000690      0  0.000000  0.844402
69 -0.011832  0.304410  0.073466  0.196126  0.122480  0.357669 -0.093669  0.218450  0.067946  0.000000  0.785464      1 -0.093669  1.000000
70  0.024688  0.381320  0.106633  0.152874  0.005507  0.174943  0.168891  0.074552  0.000690  0.785464  0.000000      1  0.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: Простите, а вы не могли бы привести пример с использованием df.apply(Fun(), axis=1) ? Например вычислить минимум для первого столбца и максимум для второго.  Насколько я понимаю, вычисление происходят построчно и как-то не клеется с возвращением датафрейма для каждой строки